# How to apply different animation on the same text when two different buttons are clicked

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a button that when clicked will display a `<p> text <p/>` element and I gave it an animation (going from top to bottom) but now I created another button that when clicked will delete the text in the `<p>` element I want to add an animation for when that happens, but when I code the CSS to animate the text when deleted, it seems to override the previous animation.

Is there an if else statement in CSS or can I do it in JavaScript?
This is vanilla JavaScript and CSS.

```html
<button class="button" onclick="Click()">click me</button>
<p id="appear" hidden>This text should appear on click</p>

<button class="butremove" onclick="ClickRemove()">click me to delete message</button>
```

```css
@keyframes buttonappear { 
  0% {top: 10px;}
  100% {top: 175px;}
}

#appear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 175px;
  animation-name: buttonappear;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
}
```

```js
const Click = () => {
  document.getElementById("appear").style.display = "block";
}

const ClickRemove = () => {
  document.getElementById("appear").style.display = "none";
}
```

What CSS or JS code can I use to animate the text when it disappears without overriding the previous animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `@keyframes` animation, you can use the `transition` property and toggle a CSS class on the `<p>` element. Since you want to perform the animation in response to an action, `transition` works perfectly for this case. Also reversing states mid-animation is handled automatically.

Here's an example:

The approach here is to set the hidden styles on the `<p>` element and define a separate class (`visible`) that contains the visible styles. Depending on which button is clicked, the `visible` class will be added to or removed from the `<p>` element and the `transition` will animate between the two styles.

```js
const message = document.querySelector("#message");

function clickShow() {
  message.classList.add("visible");
}

function clickRemove() {
  message.classList.remove("visible");
}
```

```css
#message {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 2.5s;
}

#message.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 175px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="clickShow()">click me</button>
<p id="message">This text should appear on click</p>

<button class="butremove" onclick="clickRemove()">click me to delete message</button>
```

Actually the code above can be simplified quite a bit if you want by only using one button that just toggles the message, like this:

```js
const message = document.querySelector("#message");

function toggleMessage() {
  message.classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

```css
#message {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 2.5s;
}

#message.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 175px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="toggleMessage()">click me</button>
<p id="message">This text should appear on click</p>
```